# Enable Access to Programs in Guest Account in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have a default administrator account with Open Office installed. I've recently enabled the Guest-Account for others to use. Open Office isn't available in the Guest-Account. How can I grant access of Open Office to the Guest Account?

Comment: So did you try any of the presented solutions bellow ? Did it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Login in to  your admin user account.

2) Click on Start and then right click on 'All Programs' then select 'Open all Users'.  Here you will find links to programs available to all users.  Leave this window open.

3) Click on Start again and right click on All Programs then select 'Open'.  Here is where are programs that only you can run.  Notice the file path at the top of this screen.

4) Click in the open gray area to the right of 'Start Menu'.  You can edit this line to jump to the guest or other users you have set up, and then when done editing hit return to move you to their start button directory.

5) Now you can drag and drop and/or drag a copy of program items between these various directories to allow or disallow various users access to your programs.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work in Windows 8.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the heads up about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to allow all programs in Guest account.

1. Log on to Admin profile.
2. Open Windows Explorer. Right Click on C drive icon. Go to Properties.
3. Click on Security. Click Edit. Click Add. Click Advanced.Then click Find Now. 4. After clicking this,various types of user profiles will be shown below. Select the user profile in which you want to get access to all programs, like Guest profile.After selecting press OK.
4. Then your desired profile is shown in a box. Click OK again.
5. Now you will find yourself in a previous box. Just select your desired profile and then in the box below check Full Control. Then press OK.
6. Then the Security tab appears and you can see that your profile has been allowed.Then press OK and you're done.

For C drive,after clicking OK some error or faults may appear.You just keep on click "Continue". Repeat the same process for D & E drives as well.

Comment: **Danger!** This is very likely to break Windows components because it overwrites all files' DACLs. Additionally, this procedure effectively makes that user an administrator because it can then modify all documents and important system files.

Comment: Is your spacebar broken?

Answer (score 0):

Find the program or file you want to make accessible to the Guest Account, in our example Open Office. Right click on the program icon and go to the tab security. Now you will see Group and Names, click Edit and then click Add. Now in the Box `"Enter the object names to select write"` write Guest and click Check Names. If you get it right Windows will write the Full Path  of the Guest Account. And now in the Permissions for Guest Account you can give the Account Full Control, just check the box of your choice and click Apply. Put a icon of the program on the Desktop. Try this method out and tell me if it worked cause I am interested too.

[image: Add Programs to Guest Account]

Comment: Hi - I found the instructions for the other answer easier to follow (step by step numbering), used that and it worked. Cheers.

Comment: If it worked its ok. There are no steps because it is just one click on the program and then adding the Account to grand access.