# How to decide what apps can be run from the 'Guest account'?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, uac, privileges

Let's say I want people to only be able to run VLC, Wordpad and Internet Explorer/Edge when they login to my PC with the guest account (not password protected). How do I go about this?

Comment: what windows version? http://superuser.com/questions/693047/enable-access-to-programs-in-guest-account-in-windows-7

Comment: @Pathfinder Windows 10...

Comment: Look here: --> [How to Restrict Guest Users to One App in Windows 10](http://windows.wonderhowto.com/how-to/restrict-guest-users-one-app-windows-10-0164584/)... I'll be glad to add this as an answer if it works for you. Here's a YouTube.com video [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJrChXqmYO0)

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE, thanks but this only seems to be able to set up _one_ app, not multiple. Plus, it also works only on Enterprise and Professional versions..

Comment: @RahulBasu I added an answer that should work with the part in the instruction that shows an example of allowing explicit apps. This way doesn't seem to have the constraints as the Assigned Access feature.

Comment: You can do this with local group polices.

Comment: @Ramhound I looked into that first for the OP but it appeared those policies were all or none when they are local (not to a specific users).  I know with AD you can put the user account in an OU and apply only that GPO to that OU but I didn't think this would work for local GP or I was going to pu that instruction first.  I do agree though, GP is the way to go if and/or when possible.  I didn't look into Group Policy Preferences though so perhaps there is more granular targeting with it for local GP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How to decide what apps can be run from the 'Guest account'?**
>
> Let's say I want people to only be able to run VLC, Wordpad and
>   Internet Explorer/Edge when they login to my PC with the guest account
>   (not password protected). How do I go about this?

*Follow the instructions from the below resource links to lock down a guest or some other account to only be allowed to access explicit applications which you specify in a list.*

**Resources**

- [Windows 10 Parental Controls](http://www.howtogeek.com/225323/how-to-add-and-monitor-a-childs-account-in-windows-10/)
- [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HLOtNZCrSs)

[image]

Comment: It'll work... I just hope the users won't feel underestimated as 'children'... :/